# Flutter: update widget status with notifyListeners()

Tags: flutter

I have something like this:

```
class ShareFiles extends ChangeNotifier {
  int sharingMethod = 0;

  askShareMethod(BuildContext context) {
    return showPlatformDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => PlatformAlertDialog(
        title: Text(translate("share_files_title")),
        content: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
          RadioListTile(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            value: 0,
            groupValue: sharingMethod,
            title: Text(translate('share_files_op0a')),
            subtitle: Text(translate('share_files_op0b').toLowerCase()),
            onChanged: (val) {
              sharingMethod = 0;
              notifyListeners();
            },
            selected: sharingMethod == 0 ? true : false,
          ),
          RadioListTile(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            value: 1,
            groupValue: sharingMethod,
            title: Text(translate('share_files_op1a')),
            subtitle: Text(translate('share_files_op1b').toLowerCase()),
            onChanged: (val) {
              sharingMethod = 1;
              notifyListeners();
            },
            selected: sharingMethod == 1 ? true : false,
          ),
        ]),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: PlatformText((translate('cancel'))),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: PlatformText((translate('send'))),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To call it I do:

```
await shareFiles.askShareMethod(context);
```

This generates a dialog with 2 options. When I select one the widget is not updating the status despite I'm using notifyListeners().

What am I doing wrong?

Any better option to update this value? I don't need to display `sharingMethod` anywhere else

Comment: Are u using context.watch or a Consumer widget where you want the update to perform?

Comment: just added a StatefulBuilder and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              RadioListTile(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                value: 0,
                groupValue: sharingMethod,
                title: Text(translate('share_files_op0a')),
                subtitle: Text(translate('share_files_op0b').toLowerCase()),
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    sharingMethod = 0;
                  });
                },
                selected: sharingMethod == 0 ? true : false,
              ),
              RadioListTile(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                value: 1,
                groupValue: sharingMethod,
                title: Text(translate('share_files_op1a')),
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    sharingMethod = 1;
                  });
                },
                selected: sharingMethod == 1 ? true : false,
              ),
            ],
          );
        }),
```